# Get image data from advanced custom field

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have created an image custom field using ACF which will be used as a featured image for each category. What I can't figure out is how to take that information and display it as a background image.

```
$category = get_the_category();
$category_id = $category[0]->term_id;

$category_image = get_field( 'featured_image', $category_id );
var_dump($category_image);
```

I have used the ACF documentation to write the above but this is displayed as "NULL".

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve things out of a category, it's not quite as easy as passing just the category ID.

All taxonomies use the same layout: `'{taxname}_{term_id}'`

So, your example would be

```
$category_image = get_field( 'featured_image', 'category_' . $category_id );
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to UP this but thanks dude, been stuck on this for a few good hours...

Comment: That's alright.  I think you should be able to mark it as accepted answer, though.  Good luck!.